# How to delete debug apk in flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, debugging

How to delete debug apk in flutter project ?
I want to delete all debug apks of flutter projects using terminal How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `flutter clean` in your terminal and dont forget to run `flutter pub get` after this.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal hit `flutter clean` command , after that hit `flutter pub get`. Your all apk's will be delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the entire project's cache to reclaim extra disk space or remove problematic packages and debug APKs.

Run `flutter pub cache clean` in the terminal at the project directory, and don't forget to run `flutter pub get` afterward.